# Session not created error while using chromedriver with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting below error in my selenium script.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
```

Current browser version is 94.0.4606.61 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Though I'm using chromedriver version 94 only but every time it is giving me this version 91 error. I've tried with explicitly giving path in `setProperty` and used `bonegracia` library as well.
However, this error in not getting resolved. My current browser version is displaying correctly here `(94.0.4606.61).`

Comment: "I'm using chromedriver version 94" No you are not! The error message says so. Show us **how** you are setting everything up.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update the `chromedriver.exe` file with respect to you `Chrome` version.

Refer this like https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and download `If you are using Chrome version 94, please download ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61` since as per the error message you `Chrome` browser version is `94.0.4606.61`.

Answer (score 0):

The chromedriver you currently have is of version `91`. The chromedriver version needs to match with your browser version (Chrome in your case). So, you need to download `chromedriver version 94` and replace your current one with it.

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm using chromedriver version 94" No you are not! The error message says so. Show > us how you are setting everything up.

> You might need to update the chromedriver.exe file with respect to you
> Chrome version.

> The chromedriver you currently have is of version 91. The chromedriver version
> needs to match with your browser version (Chrome in your case). So, you need to
> download chromedriver version 94 and replace your current one with it.

I don´t think that is the case, guys. I think this might be a bug.
You all seem to doubt he has the right versions, but I think he does have the right ones.

**I know how to update the chromedriver version, did it plenty of times before and I´m getting the same error**.

Think there´s something wrong with this version 94.0.4606.61.

I downloaded and unziped the chromedriver 94.0.4606.61 version from here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=94.0.4606.61/

The windows version, to be more precise:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/94.0.4606.61/chromedriver_win32.zip

But even so, when I try to run the script I get the message:

> Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only
> supports Chrome version 92 Current browser version is 94.0.4606.61
> with binary path C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

And before anyway say otherwise: **no, I´m not using driver version 92**.

Tried out every chromedriver 94´s windows versions and even the 95´s without success.

I think this chromedriver version or Chrome Browser Update might have a bug or something as I made sure to have matching Chrome Browser and chomedriver versions.

Edit: A Chrome Browser reinstall solved the issue for me.